# Why do table borders in a PDF look like they don't align properly?

Tags: pdf

I've noticed this behavior in a few different PDFs created by a few different programs (including InDesign).

[image: table border]

This only occurs when zoomed out. When you zoom in, the border looks correct. It looks correct when printed as well, so it's really just a display issue.

What causes this? Is it something about PDFs in general or is it specific to Acrobat? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: This looks like a rendering issue with Acrobat Pro and not with the PDF itself. I have seen the same thing viewing at 120% but when zooming in or out removes the outside lines. Adobe Reader and Preview (Mac) show the same PDF correctly at any size.

Comment: @AndrewH I'm able to reproduce the "issue" with Adobe Reader on Windows. I wouldn't be surprised if this was viewer-specific (don't have easy access to Evince or Okular at the moment to that). But I'm still curious why this happens on PDF-level in the first place. For example, are table joins really just likes that butt up against each other? Will different PDF creators draw the same table different?

Answer (score 0):

In Word, select table, right click “Table Properties” click “Options” top and bottom cell Margins need to be set to 0”. The whole table should be selected when making the correction, otherwise it will correct just the cell you’re in.  I believe it maybe the same process for In-Design.