# Line displays differently in SumatraPDF and Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

When looking at a pdf file I noticed that a line was much thicker than it was supposed to be. Now it seems that Adobe Acrobat (both Pro and Reader) displays this line much thicker than SumatraPDF. I made sure the scaling of both programs was the same. Below are two crops at the same magnification that clearly show the problem. As I was under the impression that pdf should be platform independent, this seems like undesirable behaviour. Is this indeed the case, or am I misunderstanding something here?

For completeness, I'm using Acrobat Reader 11.0.18 and SumatraPDF 2.5.2 and the file was generated using pdflatex 2.9.5496 64-bit and pgf version 3.0.0.
Acrobat and SumatraPDF images, respectively:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why do table borders in a PDF look like they don't align properly?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75640/why-do-table-borders-in-a-pdf-look-like-they-dont-align-properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation I found a probable cause. It seems like Acrobat uses a minimum line width. Especially for these thin lines that does make a difference. This would also explain why the both readers look alike when zoomed in. My guess is Adobe opted for this behavior to improve readability.